# Django and GeoSpatial Queries on Google App Engine - How to overcome the 'one inequality per query' issue?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I've just began to use the GAE and I have stumbled upon an issue which has let me questioning the feasibility of using Django on GAE.

All I'm trying to do is a simple query with Django's ORM:

```
addresses = Address.objects.filter(lat__gte=form.cleaned_data['north_east_lat'])
addresses = addresses.filter(lat__lte=form.cleaned_data['south_west_lat'])
addresses = addresses.filter(lon__gte=form.cleaned_data['north_east_lon'])
addresses = addresses.filter(lon__lte=form.cleaned_data['south_west_lon'])
```

But apparently it's not that easy with Bigtable:

BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<=, >=, <, >)..

How can I get around this issue? (Using Django's ORM preferably)

Comment: Bear in mind that this is not a proper geospatial query: there's no way for a regular RDBMS to index this efficiently either. There's a reason many RDBMSes have geospatial toolkits with special indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to use Django's ORM to get around this issue.  However, you can do geospatial queries on GAE (including bounding box queries like you're doing in your example).  For details, please check out the [Geospatial Queries with Google App Engine using GeoModel](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geospatial.html) article.

Comment: OK, I'll drop the Django ORM and use the GAE DB API directly. Should I drop Django altogether and use the webapp framework? (My server side code is really small and simple so I'm not worrying about changing it)